# Finding data in large binary file and output with context

Tags: linux, binary, command-line-interface, extract

**Prologue / Context**

Last week my root filesystem was remounted readonly serveral times and I took a complete snapshot via ddrescue. Sadly the filesystem was damaged already and some files are missing. At the moment I try to find my ejabberd user-database which should be somewhere within the image. Testdisk found the required file (marked as deleted) but could not restore it. Since the file is pretty small and I have a backup from some month ago I thought about doing a binary search over the whole image.

So now I have a 64GB file with a damaged filesystem and would like to extract some 4kb blocks which contain a certain pattern.

**Question**

How can I find the data within the 64GB large file and extract the result with some context (4kb)?

Since the filesystem image resides on my server I would prefer a linux cli tool.

Comment: What about a simple `grep` together with its "Context Line Control" and with the search pattern having been regex escaped before?

Comment: when even testdisk fails it might get hard. what kind of filesystem was it? btw, before you start any action with the image, create a backup first.

Comment: @arkascha I tried `grep -U -b -A 20 "$(printf $'\x64\x6f\x6f')" /dev/loop0` but it only told me that was a match, but not where and did not output any of the content.

Comment: @hek2mgl in the meantime I found some of the data with [Curses Hexedit](http://www.rogoyski.com/adam/programs/hexedit/onlinedoc/hexedit.html) so the data seems to be there, but it is a highly manual and time consuming process. The disk has an ext4 filesystem. I made a copy of the ddrescue image before I startet to work on it ;-)

Comment: Is the file size less than 4kb?

Comment: @hek2mgl filesize is between 4kb and 16kb

Comment: If the file size is above 4kb it can be spread across multiple 4kb sectors - anywhere on the disk.

Comment: How did this happen? Was this the result of a BTRFS  snappy snapshot issue?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin nope, just a dying SSD. The first two times I simply rebooted the server when it had a readonly remount root directory. When it occurred the third time, I took the backup but the damaged was done already

Answer (score 0):

### The Tool

Since I couldn't find a tool which meet my requirements I wrote it myself in golang. I call it **bima** (for binary match). It isn't pretty but it did the job:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v1"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math"
    "os"
)

var (
    debug       = kingpin.Flag("debug", "Enable debug mode.").Short('d').Bool()
    bsize       = kingpin.Flag("blocksize", "Blocksize").Short('b').Default("126976").Int()
    debugDetail = kingpin.Flag("debugdetail", "Debug Detail").Short('v').Default("10").Int()

    matchCommand      = kingpin.Command("match", "Match a value")
    matchCommandValue = matchCommand.Arg("value", "The value (Hex Encoded e.g.: 616263 == abc)").Required().String()
    matchCommandFile  = matchCommand.Arg("file", "The file").Required().String()
)

func main() {
    kingpin.Version("0.1")
    mode := kingpin.Parse()

    if *bsize <= 0 {
        log.Fatal("The blocksize has to be larger than 0")
    }

    if *debugDetail <= 0 {
        log.Fatal("The Debug Detail has to be larger than 0")
    }

    if mode == "match" {
        searchBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(*matchCommandValue)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        scanFile(searchBytes, *matchCommandFile)
    }
}

func scanFile(search []byte, path string) {
    searchLength := len(search)
    blocksize := *bsize

    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    filesize := fi.Size()
    expectedRounds := int(math.Ceil(float64(filesize-int64(searchLength))/float64(blocksize)) + 1)
    if expectedRounds <= 0 {
        expectedRounds = 1
    }

    data := make([]byte, 0, blocksize+searchLength-1)
    data2 := make([]byte, 0, blocksize+searchLength-1)
    offset := make([]byte, searchLength-1)
    //reading the len of the slice or less (but not the cap)
    readCount, err := f.Read(offset)
    if err == io.EOF {
        fmt.Println("The files seems to be empty")
        return
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data = append(data, offset...)

    buffer := make([]byte, blocksize)
    var blockpos int
    var idx int
    blockpos = 0

    lastLevel := -1
    roundLevel := 0
    idxOffset := 0
    for round := 0; ; round++ {
        if *debug {
            roundLevel = ((round * 100) / expectedRounds)
            if (roundLevel%*debugDetail == 0) && (roundLevel > lastLevel) {
                lastLevel = roundLevel
                fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Starting round", round+1, "of", expectedRounds, "--", ((round * 100) / expectedRounds))
            }
        }

        //At EOF, the count will be zero and err will be io.EOF
        readCount, err = f.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                if *debug {
                    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Done - Found EOF")
                }
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        data = append(data, buffer[:readCount]...)
        data2 = data
        idxOffset = 0
        for {
            idx = bytes.Index(data2, search)
            if idx >= 0 {
                fmt.Println(blockpos + idxOffset + idx)
                if idx+searchLength < len(data2) {
                    data2 = data2[idx+searchLength:]
                    idxOffset += idx
                } else {
                    break
                }
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        data = data[readCount:]
        blockpos += readCount
    }
}
```

### The Story

For completeness here comes what I did to solve my problem:

At first I used hexedit to find out, that all db files have the same header. Encoded in hex it looks like this: `0102030463584d0b0000004b62574c41`

So I used my tool to find all occurrences within my sda.image file:

```
./bima match 0102030463584d0b0000004b62574c41 ./sda.image >DBfiles.txt
```

For the 64GB this took about 8 Minutes and I think the HDD was the limiting factor.

The result where about 1200 occurrences which I extracted from the image with dd. As I didn't know the exact size of the files I simply extracted chunks of 20.000 bytes:

```
for f in $(cat DBfiles.txt); do
    dd if=sda.image of=$f.dunno bs=1 ibs=1 skip=$f count=20000
done
```

Now I had about 1200 files and had to find the right ones. In a first step I search for the passwd files (passwd.DCD and passwd.DCL). later I did the same for the roster files. As the header of the files contains the name, I simply greped for passwd:

```
for f in *.dunno; do
    if [ "$(cat $f | head -c 200 | grep "passwd" | wc -l)" == "1" ]; then
        echo "$f" | sed 's/\.$//g' >> passwd_files.list
    fi
done
```

Because the chunks were larger than the files I had to find the end of each files manually. I did the corrections with [Curses Hexedit](http://www.rogoyski.com/adam/programs/hexedit/onlinedoc/hexedit.html).

During that process I could see that the head of each file contained either `dcl_logk` or `dcd_logk`. So I knew which of the files were DCL files and which were DCD files.

In the end I had each file up to ten times and had to decide which version  I wanted to use. In general I took the largest file. After putting the files in the DB directory of the new ejabberd server and restarting it, all accounts are back again. :-)